# standalone jdbc-pool implementation memory leak

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, connection-pooling, tomcat7

I am trying to implement jdbc-pool in a standalone web app (self contained - not relying on server.xml) so that it can be moved to tomcat installations that may be earlier than 7.0.

I am connecting to MSSQL Server with the sourceforge driver (net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver)

Everything runs fine except for this error:

> SEVERE: The web application [/jdbc-pool] appears to have started a
>   thread named [[Pool-Cleaner]:Tomcat Connection Pool[1-12524859]] but
>   has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Based on [**this**](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Cleaning-up-after-tomcat-jdbc-pool-td2108107.html) I determined that I need to close the jdbc-pool datasource. I am having trouble with this last line from that post though:

> >> If it is configured in the application context, then this simply
>   means you forgot to call DataSource.close on the connection pool when
>   your web application is stopped.
>
> > This is confusing advice because javax.sql.DataSource doesn't have
>   a close() method.
>
> **In order to call close, one has to cast it to what ever the data
>   source you are using.**

How do I find out what type of datasource I am using and where is the class for it? Can I extract it from the driver jar somehow?

In addition to a servlet which uses the pool, I am using a ServletContextListener so that I can start out with pooled connections immediately from the contextInitialized method. I started adding the code to kill the connection in the contextDestroyed method of this ServletContextListener but got hung up where the question marks are:

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class JdbcPoolListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent myServletContextEvent) {

        // initialize jdbc-pool datasource to start out with pooled connections 
        try {
            Context myContext = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
            DataSource myDataSource = (DataSource) myContext.lookup("jdbc/db");
            myServletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute("JdbcPool", myDataSource);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error initializing jdbc-pool datasource");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent myServletContextEvent) {

        // failed attempt to close the data source
        ServletContext myServletContext = myServletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        //DataSource myDataSource = (DataSource) myServletContext.getAttribute("JdbcPool");
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)((???) myServletContext.getAttribute(contextAttribute)).getConfiguration().getEnvironment().getDataSource();
        dataSource.close();
        myServletContext.removeAttribute("JdbcPool");

        // deregister JDBC driver to prevent Tomcat 7 from complaining about memory leaks
        Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
        while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
            Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
            try {
                DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
                System.out.println(String.format("Deregistering jdbc driver: %s", driver));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Error deregistering driver %s", driver));
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in your particular case it is most likely net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource and try to play with socketTimeout settings this will close connection if it idles. more in the docs of the driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved this, I noticed that the `tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy` had a close method, so I cast the datasource as a `DataSourceProxy`, then called closed on it. I no longer get the tomcat memory leak error in the log now.

**SOLUTION:**

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy;

public class JdbcPoolListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent myServletContextEvent) {

        // initialize jdbc-pool datasource to start out with pooled connections 
        try {
            Context myContext = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
            DataSource myDataSource = (DataSource) myContext.lookup("jdbc/cf");
            myServletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute("JdbcPool", myDataSource);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error initializing jdbc-pool datasource");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent myServletContextEvent) {

    // close datasource from proxy?
    ServletContext myServletContext = myServletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        DataSourceProxy myDataSource = (DataSourceProxy) myServletContext.getAttribute("JdbcPool");
        myDataSource.close();       
        myServletContext.removeAttribute("JdbcPool");

        // deregister JDBC driver to prevent Tomcat 7 from complaining about memory leaks
        Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
        while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
            Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
            try {
                DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
                System.out.println(String.format("Deregistering jdbc driver: %s", driver));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Error deregistering driver %s", driver));
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess if you had used the org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource class you would get the same result because it extends the DataSourceProxy and the DataSourceProxy implements the PoolConfiguration and the DataSourceProxy has the close() method to close the pool.